# How to find the actor who has acted in the maximum number of movie and 3rd busiest actor

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, greatest-n-per-group

Got 2 tables

[image]

Table 1 - ACTOR : ACTOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, LAST_UPDATE

Table 2 - FILM_ACTOR : ACTOR_ID, FILM_ID, LAST_UPDATE

I have tried the below on finding who has acted in max no of movies

```
select top 1 concat(ACTOR.FIRST_NAME, ACTOR.LAST_NAME) as Full_name
from ACTOR
left join FILM_ACTOR on ACTOR.ACTOR_ID = FILM_ACTOR.ACTOR_ID
group by FILM_ACTOR.ACTOR_ID
order by Full_name desc;
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And please clarify which RDBMS you're using

Comment: `MySQL` <> `SQL Server` so, don't tag the irrelevant tags.

Comment: No such thing as varchar2 in sql server. And timestamp datatype has no relationship to date or time. So this probably isn't related to SQL Server.

Comment: Yep, this appears to be about Oracle

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried the below on finding who has acted in max no of movies.

Your original query is quite close - you just need the proper order by clause:

```
select top (1) concat(a.first_name, a.last_name) as full_name
from actor a
left join film_actor fa on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
group by a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want the *nth* busiest actor, then one option is to use window functions:

```
select full_name
from (
    select concat(a.first_name, a.last_name) as full_name, row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from actor a
    left join film_actor fa on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
    group by a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name
) t
where rn = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation : :

```
select a.*
from actor a 
where a.actor_id = (select top (1) fm.actor_id 
                    from film_actor fm 
                    group by fm.actor_id 
                    order by count(*) desc
                   );
```